# What is the metric name or designation for nominal ½″ copper pipe in the various English dialects where metric dimensions are used?

Tags: terminology, transatlantic-differences, measuring-units

I hope this question is as on-topic as [this question about distances](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22622/what-are-the-distances-among-the-major-english-dialects).

I need to know what people call nominal ½″ copper pipe (the stiff unbendable kind used in domestic plumbing) in English dialects where such things are stated in metric units rather than in nominal imperial units.

Comment: It's 15 mm piping. It can be bent with a pipe bending tool. The 3/4" size is now 22 mm.

Comment: The question might be a better fit on [SE Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: For what purpose? https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/cts-copper-tubing-sizes-d_2112.html

Comment: @Lambie it's for domestic plumbing.

Comment: @WeatherVane  I meant for other purposes: like literary translation or telling a French person our size of pipe, etc. In those cases, it might be different. I don't know if he wants the exact meaning or not. The EU measurements are not the same...Generally, one's country has its own measurements for what they actually use. So unless they are importing American piples, one has to look to that English-speaking country that uses the same exact size but in millimeters.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper_tubing round the world!

Comment: Americans do ɴᴏᴛ use the term ‘ɪᴍᴘᴇʀɪᴀʟ ᴜɴɪᴛꜱ’ for these: [*“The two systems used for specifying units of measure are **the English and metric systems**. …The basic units for length or distance measurements in the **English system** are the inch, foot, yard, and mile. Other units of length also include the rod, furlong, and chain. survey foot definition. In **the English system**, areas are typically given in square feet or square yards.”*](https://www.dot.state.wy.us/files/live/sites/wydot/files/shared/Highway_Development/Surveys/Survey%20Manual/Appendix%20G%20-%20Units%20of%20Measure.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

15mm copper pipe is also known as Type L copper pipe. That is probably what you are looking for, but some less commonly used names: copper rounds, blue stamp, and for the imperialists 1/2 inch copper pipe (even though it’s not 1/2 and is 15mm).

Comment: The apparent difference (15 mm not the exact 12.7 mm) is because with the change to metric, the nominal outside diameter is used instead of the internal diameter.

Comment: *Sed nunc nullum imperium Romanum est.* :)

Comment: Type L is the thickness. K, L, and M being the common weights.

Comment: Blue stamp also refers to the type specification. Not sure if the color coding is standardized across countries.